# asp.net bootstrap alert data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, bootstrapping

Need help on bootstrap alert function,below is my code that use to popup alert.

```
            <div id="asd" runat="server">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="success-alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong> Pending Approval-HR(Please approve now)</strong> <a href="CEO_m.aspx" style="color: red" class="alert-link">Click to redirect</a>
                </div>
        </div>
```

The alert text i want get from Database as well as url.The total alert will popup is depend on total data from database.

[image]

Comment: Hi Lim, your question is not clear. Where you stuck ?

Comment: In bootstrap we use `modal` class to popup some dialogs.

Comment: so should use modal instead of alert?

Comment: if you looking for this kind of alert yes you should use modal - https://www.google.lk/search?q=modal+in+bootstrap&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=837&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiDo9SLnd7OAhXKQ48KHawKBk8Q_AUIBygC#imgrc=QXZfVNdzs0J7EM%3A

Comment: but some of the browser blocked pop-out,thats why i decide to try alert haha

Comment: bootstrap alerts are something different - http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp I think you want to use pure js - `Alert.show("Your Message")`. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear. Use ajax alert may fix your problem

```
string message = "alert('Hello! Mudassar.')";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(),    "alert", message, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Session variable Or Label and set value from database .

```
<div id="asd" runat="server">
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="success-alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
       <strong> Pending Approval-HR(Please approve now)</strong> <a href="CEO_m.aspx" style="color: red" class="alert-link"><asp:Label ID="lbl_text" Text=""/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```